How import data to rows in table by drag data from excel and drop (react native)?
I try to enter data in multi rows by one click (drag from excel and paste to rows) in react native,
not found anything.
can you suggest tips or lead me?
I don't found  ready component.
I use react-native-paper to create table (but not important if need change it ).

First you need to implement a file picker method. You can use something similar to react-native-document-picker do this. Then you can use the picked file and use a parser like Papa Parse to convert it to JSON format. This JSON can be used to render your UI.
